# How can I handle control resizing when rotating screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Whilst 90% of my controls resize perfectly with the snapping features. I have some elements which are sized programmatically due to their contents (i.e a label and its container) in the ViewDidLoad function.

Is there anyway to get a handle on the screen rotation event? So I can perform my control resizing manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Assuming you're using a `UIViewController`—which you definitely should be—you just need to implement the `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method. Re-configure your views in an animation block in that.

Answer (score 0):

I hadnt realised there was a delegate for:

didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation

I put my code in there, job done